# Using Jigsaw's Outline VPN on Amazon Kindle and fire stick

Tags: vpn

I travel a lot, in certain countries I do not have full access to the Internet. I recently set up a VPN, using [Outline](https://getoutline.org/) and hosting on Google infrastructure. I then installed the client apps on my android and apple phones as well as PC.

All this works great, but I also use Amazon Kindle and Amazon Firestick. Neither seems to have the Outline client on the app store. I want to avoid jailbreaking the devices. But, what options do I have?

I've tried using my cell phone, running Outline VPN, as a hotspot but the connected devices don't seem to go through the VPN (I can confirm this by looking at the ip addresses of the connected devices) Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: When I've tried to use a VPN client or connect kindles etc through my phone hotspot in other countries, it was blocked by my carrier as not being allowed when roaming (use Three in the UK). Could it be a call to them to see if they can allow it? {(They may not due to policy).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just side loading the client to my Fire Stick.  It works fine that way.  First, I had to enable the developer environment, then install a mouse application, then I installed a side loading app on my cellphone.  THis allowed me to push the VPN client from my phone to the Fire Stick.  It works fine this way.